# Fopen taking too long to start download

Tags: php

I am trying to download 700mb file using the following code

```
header("Pragma: public", true);
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($File));
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");             
header("Content-Length: " . filesize('movies/'.$File));
flush(); 

$fp = fopen('movies/'.$File, "r"); 
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536); 
    flush(); 
}  
fclose($fp);
```

but this is taking too long to start downloading file, it takes about 2-3 minutes to start the download. This code is just for mkv file, other video files are working perfect with location header.

File is not downloading without any of the content-type header missing

I want to start downloading fast

Comment: setting the same header multiple times is pointless. you can't have multiple content-types anyways: "This download is an apple, an elephant, and a beat up volkswagen".

Comment: ok i have edited my code

Comment: Read manual for that function: http://php.net/flush You can find some tips to try there.

Comment: Done :) added ob_flush() after flush() only and its working

Comment: a simple readfile() won't do? http://docs.php.net/readfile